# how to checkout triggered build branch details in jenkins file

Tags: git, jenkins, aws-codecommit

i have two repositories 
TestCIRepository - which has jenkins file
TestSeperateCI- Which has source code 
CISeperationTest-is my jenkins job

CodeCommit Url:

[image]

Pipeline details:

[image]

What I configured so far is when i commit changes to source code i can trigger build 
jenkins script file:

[image]

jenkins console output:

[image]

What i need now is to have details of branch that triggered build, that is my source code branch details and want to run stages(build/test/deploy) on this.How to achieve this??? Can anyone help please